# string replacement with regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, string

I have field in sql db contains the formula of dynamic calculated question
here in my example I have the following string `(q1)+(q2)`.

How can I replace `q1` and `q2 ... qn` , to this
`eval($(q1).val())+eval($(q2).val())`

I need code in c# or javascript to do that .

this is my c# code do replacement (q1),(q2),..(qn) with eval($(q**1**).val()) ,
but i need to get q dynamically

```
`string _equation = dr["calc_equation"].ToString();
 _equation = Regex.Replace(_equation, @"[(]q[0-9][)]+", "eval($(q1).val())");`
```

Comment: Would [math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) be of use to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```js
const f = '(q1)+(q2)';

console.log(f.replace(/\([a-z]\d\)/g,  'eval($$$&.val())'));
```

Thr first `$` escapes the second `$`, and the `$&` represents each match.

If there can be more then one letter then use `[a-z]+`.

Comment: thank you so much , this is solve my problem